# Why a Christoffel connection is inconsistent with local supersymmetry?

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity

I'm doing an introductory studying on supergravity, and I'm studying in particular on the book *Supergravity* of D. Z. Freedman and A.V. Proeyen. In this book they describe supersymmetry using Majorana supercharges when possible. For instance in $D=4$ dimension and for one supersymmetry $\mathcal{N}=1$, the supercharges anticomutation rule is

\begin{equation}
\left\{Q_\alpha,\bar{Q}^{\beta}\right\}= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma^\mu\right)_\alpha{}^{\beta}P_\mu
\end{equation}
Moreover I will use the following notation

- $D_\mu$ is the covariant derivative containing only the spin connection, hence for istance on spinor we have
  \begin{equation}
  D_\mu\psi = \left(\partial_\mu+\frac{1}{4}\omega_{\mu ab}\gamma^{ab}\right)\psi
  \end{equation}
- $\nabla_\mu$ is the covariant derivative containing also the possible affine connection term, hence for instance on a spin 3/2 field we have
  \begin{equation}
  \nabla_\mu\psi_\nu= \left(\partial_\mu+\frac{1}{4}\omega_{\mu ab}\gamma^{ab}\right)\psi_\nu - \Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}\psi_\rho
  \end{equation}

$\mathcal{N}=1$ in $D=4$ dimension pure supergravity (i.e. no matter coupling) is described by an action containing only the vielbein field $e^\mu_a$ describing the graviton, and the Majorana Rarita - Schwinger field $\psi_\mu$, describing the gravitino. The action is

\begin{equation}
S =\frac{1}{2k^2}\int d^4x\,e\left\{e^{a\mu}e^{b\nu}R_{\mu\nu ab}-\bar{\psi}_\mu\gamma^{\mu\nu\rho}D_{\nu}\psi_{\rho}\right\}
\end{equation}

where $k^2 = 8\pi G$ ($G$ being the Newton constant) and, as ususal, $\gamma^{\mu\nu\rho}$ is the totally antisymmetrize product of three $\gamma$-matrices.

One can work in the first order formalism, and then consider the variation of the action with respect to the spin connection $\omega$. Thus one gets an equation for the spin connection that can be solved to obtain a connection with torsion.

Now my problem is, why in the action there is $D_\mu$ only and not $\nabla_\mu$? I mean:

- If we have zero torsion then of course we don't have any affine connection, because this one would be symmetric in the lower indices which are contracted with the antisymmetric one of $\gamma^{\mu\nu\rho}$
- When we have torsion though (and in the first order formalism we do find a non zero torsion) the above reasoning doesn't work anymore. However Freedman and Proeyen sais

> We don't have any Christoffel connection in the action because this would be inconsistent with local supersymmetry

I really can't understand why. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Which page in F&P?

Comment: Chapter 9, page 191